# Why some standards are called Request For Comments?

Tags: terminology, protocol

Is it just historic name or it has some real ground?

Should I use the term "request for comments, RFC" when putting some document just to receive comments, not to establish a standard?

Comment: As well as being off topic, it's probably also subjective and argumentative. Voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request for Comments system is a vehicle adopted by the [Internet Engineering Task Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) as a means for publishing material for peer review, or possibly just the conveyance of new ideas, which through iteration may, or may not, become standards.

Whilst the RFC system is typically the province of the IETF and to a lesser extent, other computer network engineers, other professions also have similar processes, whereby, someone may publish a document, which is then subject to peer review, etc. This is particularly true in the scientific community.

Comment: So I should not use the term "request for comment" when it is related neither to IETF nor to some other standard, right?

Comment: If the document you create is for an internal process, I guess you could call it whatever you like. If, however, it's to be a public document, I think you would need to consider it's content and its audience. You may find that within specific disciplines, there are more appropriate formats.

Answer (score 4):

It is historic. Those documents [used to be](http://www.livinginternet.com/i/ia_rfc.htm) just recommendations between peers. Someone would have one problem and he would write RFC to find out whether his solution was ok. At some stage those documents just got to be official reference for quite few things but name was kept same.

Do notice that, while they are much more serious than in early days, not all RFCs are to be considered as standard. Quite few of them are just some idea or even [joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools'_Day_RFC).